# Haskell way to joint two small functions. Syntax advice needed

Tags: haskell, syntax, online-compilation

I'm new to Haskell and I'm having kind of a hard time joining two sections of code for this program. What it does (or should do) is to let me know if a triangle is isosceles by the theorem of cosenes. Here it is what I thought would work:

```
--Determine if a triangle is isosceles by the cosene theroem

module Main where
sides :: (Float, Float, Float) -> (Float, Float, Float)
sides (a, b, c) = (x, y, z)
 where
   x = acos((b^2 + c^2 - a^2) / (2 * b * c))
   y = acos((a^2 + c^2 - b^2) / (2 * a * c))
   z = acos((a^2 + b^2 - c^2) / (2 * a * b))  

theorem :: (Float, Float, Float) -> String
theorem (x, y, z)
  |(x==y && x/=z) = "Es isosceles"
  |(x==z && x/=y) = "Es isosceles"
  |(y==z && y/=x) = "No es isosceles"
 
main :: IO()
main = do
   print "Please type the size of the triangle faces: "
   (a, b, c) <- getLine
   (x, y, z) <- sides (a, b, c)
   string <- theorem(x, y, z)
   print string
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that after my advice updated code will run, but I see some problems in this code:

1. `print` isn't exactly what you want, because strings will be printing with quotes (`"Please type the size of the triangle faces: "` instead `Please type the size of the triangle faces:` ). If you want print a string, replace `print` to `putStrLn`
2. `getLine` has type `IO String`, so pattern matching with `(a, b, c)` will be failed. But you can write `read <$> getLine` - it will apply function `read` which convert a string to a value of any readable type (in this case it is `(Float, Float, Float)`) to the input string. But the input string must be in format `(_, _, _)` (for example `(1, 1, 1)`)
3. when you write `a <- b` in do-block, it means that `b` has type `m t` where `m` is `Monad`, and `a` has type `t`. `sides` has type `(Float, Float, Float) -> (Float, Float, Float)`, so you can't write this instead `b` in the expression above. But you can write `let a = b` where both `a` and `b` has the same type `t`. So you can write `let (x, y, z) = sides (a, b, c)` instead `(x, y, z) <- sides (a, b, c)`. Similarly with `string <- theorem(x, y, z)`
4. `theorem` don't defined for all values `(x, y, z)` because you consider cases with the pair of equals value and one not equal